# Remove shortcut arrow only on desktop?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, desktop

How can you remove the little arrow on the bottom of every shortcut icon, except I *only want to remove it on the desktop*. I think I can make a small program with whichever icon I want that acts as a shortcut icon, but is there a built in way, or an easier hack?

Comment: All the solutions I've seen so far make a global change. Since the shell handles this I doubt you can restrict it to a single folder/location.

Answer (score 1):

Check `Shell Icons` value `29` command:

```
REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons" /v "29"
```

Remove desktop shorcut.

RemoveDescArrow.cmd:

```
::     Clear shorcut
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons" /v "29"  /t REG_SZ  /d  "%windir%\system32\shell32.dll,50" /f
::     Clear Icon Cache DB XP/2003
ver | findstr "5.1 5.2" && del /F /A:- /Q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\IconCache.db"
::     Clear Icon Cache DB Vista/7/2008/2008 R2
ver | findstr "6.0 6.1" && del /F /A:- /Q "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db"
::     logoff
shutdown /l
```

RestoreDescArrow.cmd:

```
::     Clear shorcut
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons" /v "29"  /t REG_SZ  /d  "%windir%\system32\shell32.dll,29" /f
::     Clear Icon Cache DB XP/2003
ver | findstr "5.1 5.2" && del /F /A:- /Q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\IconCache.db"
::     Clear Icon Cache DB Vista/7/2008/2008 R2
ver | findstr "6.0 6.1" del /F /A:- /Q "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db"
::     logoff
shutdown /l
```

command line, additional variant:

```
REG Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons" /v "29" /f
```

Comment: +1 because this is helpful, but it's not the answer because I wanted something that applies **only** to the desktop, not in Windows Explorer.

Comment: and the REG ADD code to restore the shortcut makes it look like the Windows 95 one instead of Windows 7

Comment: @leaf68 Thx! use `REG Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons" /v "29"`